# How to edit application.properties during runtime (for next time use)

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, lua, application.properties

I want to be able to check if a script exists in a Redis cluster. If it doesn't, I will need to load a new script from my `resources folder` and save the corresponding SHA value of that new script. I would like to save that SHA value for next time the application starts up, inside of the `application.properties`. This would ideally be done by overwriting the previous entry for the sha value

I know that the properties file is read once during startup, but this does not matter as I only want to save that SHA value to the `application.properties` for use next time, ie preventing the overhead of checking for a script and loading each time.

This is my method for preparing the scripts

```
static String prepareScripts() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    List <Boolean> list = (List) asyncCommands.scriptExists(sha).get();
    shaDigest = sha;
    if (list.get(0) == false) {
        URL url = AbstractRedisDao.class.getClassLoader().getResource("script.txt");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "ISO_8859_1");
        shaDigest = (String) asyncCommands.scriptLoad(str).get();

        Properties  properties = new Properties();


        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("application.properties");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            Iterator propertyIt =  properties.entrySet().iterator();

            while (propertyIt.hasNext() ) {
                Map.Entry nextHolder = (Map.Entry) propertyIt.next();
                while (nextHolder.getKey() != ("redis.scriptActiveDev")) {
                    bw.write(nextHolder.getKey() + "=" + nextHolder.getValue());
                }
            }

            bw.write("redis.scriptActiveDev=" + shaDigest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
        return shaDigest;
    } else {
        return shaDigest;
    }
}
```

these are the details for redis in application.properties:

```
redis.enabled=true
redis.hostname=xxxx
redis.port=xxxx
redis.password=xxxx
redis.sha=xxxx
```

Is this on the right track? also, how would i go about saving the `application.properties` back to the `resources` folder after rebuilding it with the new property? Is there a more efficient way to do this without recreating the whole `application.properties` just to add one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to store SHA digests for Lua scripts in `application.properties`.

Use the API of your Redis client to get SHA digest on application startup.

For instance, Lettuce provides the following [API](https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/4.4.0.Final/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/api/sync/RedisScriptingCommands.html) for scripting:
`String digest(V script)`
`String scriptLoad(V script)`
`List<Boolean> scriptExists(String... digests)`

You can execute the following code on each application startup to get the digest for your script:

```
public String sha(String script) {
  String shaDigest = redisScriptingCommands.digest(script);
  boolean scriptExists = redisScriptingCommands.scriptExists(shaDigest).get(0);
  if (!scriptExists) {
    redisScriptingCommands.scriptLoad(script);
  }
  return shaDigest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize your configuration in a folder outside the classpath.

```
 java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/var/config
```

> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> 1. A config subdirectory of the current directory
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath /config package
> 4. The classpath root
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).
>
> If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths).

[Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)